# Aligning the controls in a DIV

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My second week of learning and doing WebDevelopment! I have written this `Bootstrap` layout and the result is in the picture below.
**Note the areas marked as yellow?** why is that happening? How can I fix it? I know I can for example play around with `margin-left` ,etc.. to make it look right but I am still thinking if I define they correctly in `bootstrap`, it shouldn't have this problem.

**Here is the Bootply to see the issue**: http://www.bootply.com/zRyxHyhdbM

**Here is the generated HTML code:**

```
<div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1 text-right"><label class="control-label" for="Email">Email</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input id="AdminEmail" name="AdminEmail" style="width:100%;padding-right:30px;" type="text" value="">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback" style="right: 10px; line-height: 27px;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div>
                            <input class="checkbox-inline" id="ShowAdminPhone" name="ShowAdminPhone" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="ShowAdminPhone" type="hidden" value="false">
                            <label class="control-label" for="Show_Admin_phone">Show Admin phone</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
 </div>


 <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1 text-right"><label class="control-label" for="Phone">Phone</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
                        <input class="col-sm-2" id="AdminPhone" name="AdminPhone" type="text" value="">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="Ext">Ext</label>
                        <input class="col-sm-2" id="AdminExt" name="AdminExt" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: you need to show your code

Comment: @dippas oh sorry :( yes updated with code. Thank you.

Comment: That's the raw code, sow us the HTML generated code, for better assistance

Comment: @dippas Ok thank you, I added generated HTML to my question too.

Comment: @Paulie_D I updated the question with generated HTML . Thanks.

Comment: I think you're missing some...the email section?

Comment: Basically, try making a demo that reproduces the issue. We can't do that from the code you are supplying .

Comment: Added a jsFiddle link as an edit to this post: https://jsfiddle.net/rfvrbfs8/

Comment: Please update the html markup for email

Comment: Have you wrapped the section in a `<div class="form-inline">` as per http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline?

Comment: Thanks all, I added a Bootplay to exactly reproduce the issue. Added the link to it in my question too.  http://www.bootply.com/zRyxHyhdbM

Comment: @Paulie_D ok I added a Bootply of the generated code that reproduces the issue. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The misalignment is there because, the email input box is col-sm-4. To align bottom inputs we have to fit them with in col-sm-4. You can add margin-left(approx 12px) to align it but it will not be responsive.
Hence, I have changed the markup a little bit to remain responsive--
Link --- http://www.bootply.com/x0fgleMTp2

```
    <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1 text-right"><label class="control-label" for="Email">Email</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input id="AdminEmail" name="AdminEmail" style="width:100%;padding-right:30px;" type="text" value="">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback" style="right: 10px; line-height: 27px;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div>
                            <input class="checkbox-inline" id="ShowAdminPhone" name="ShowAdminPhone" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="ShowAdminPhone" type="hidden" value="false">
                            <label class="control-label" for="Show_Admin_phone">Show Admin phone</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
 </div>


 <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1 text-right"><label class="control-label" for="Phone">Phone</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 multi-row">
                      <span class="col-sm-5"><input class="form-input" id="AdminPhone" name="AdminPhone" type="text" value=""></span>
                      <span class="col-sm-2"><label class="control-label" for="Ext">Ext</label></span>
                      <span class="col-sm-5"><input class="form-input" id="AdminExt" name="AdminExt" type="text" value=""></span>
                    </div>  
 </div>
```

Comment: great.  One last tweak: How can I get the "Ext" label closer to its text box? currently it is too far.  Is it safe to use Padding and Margin stuff? or there is bootstrap way for it? Thanks again.

Comment: If still it doesn't match your requirement, add class and use margin in %.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you wanted to achieve? Hope it may help.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail3">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
      <div class="form-inline"> 
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail3">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Phone">
      </div>
    <div class="form-group pull-right">
           <label for="exampleInputEmail3">Ext</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Ext">
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69nk6wjp/2/)